# Force lock for all modified files in svn

Tags: svn

I want to have my automated build system steal locks from all modified files before commiting, I know it can be done by force locking but

```
svn lock --force
```

requires me to name a file that I want to lock, is there a way to tell it to lock all modified files

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn status -u` in your working copy or `svn status -u --xml` for xml'ed output. See [SVNBook | Discovering locks](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/locking/#svn.advanced.locking.discovery) and [`svn status`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/status/).

Comment: That just gives me information on what files are modifed, how can I use it to unlock it? This needs to be done automatically in a jenkins pipeline so I cannot rely on maually typing everything that status gives me

Comment: @SzymonO please read the provided links. The option `-u` - among other things - fetches the data about locks from the server and shows the `O` character near locked files. The `--xml` shows the xml'ed output which you can parse and find locked files in a script.